# Implementing a method that returns a Class

Tags: java, class

There is an interface with a method that returns a Class, like so.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    
    public Class<? extends Object> returnsSomething ();
}
```

I have to create a class which implements the interface, like so.

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    
    public Class<? extends Object> returnsSomething () {
        
        return Object; // This is currently an error.
    }
}
```

The `return` line in the implementation of `returnsSomething` in `MyClass` is incorrect. The IDE hints "cannot find symbol Object".

What correction do I need to apply in `returnSomething`'s body to compile successfully?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `return Object.class;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object` is just the name of the class.

`Object.class` is the instance of the `Class<Object>` class that represents the `Object` class. See [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

So you need:

```
return Object.class;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your return type is incorrect in your method. You need to understand that this '.class' is used in Java for code Reflection. Generally you can gather meta data for your class such as the full qualified class name, list of constants, list of public fields,etc...  So in your example you are basically saying that the Class type to be returned for the wildcard used will either be Object or Subclass of object to be returned at Runtime. Note that you want Java to determine the object returned at Runtime.

Comment: Sorry, very confusing answer - maybe you should try to explain with some code sample?

Comment: @GyroGearless you might want to read [this](https://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/java/javaOO/genwildcard.html) and then [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html) . For the part of the answer, I have explained his code. You can make reference.